# Data not inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a simple web form in which you input data into and then it is posted into the database, when submitting the information it is submitted correctly but when I view it in the table the data is invisible.

query

```
CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
    `id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `recipename` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
    `ingredients` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
    `instructions` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

php code

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="my username"; // Left empty due to privacy
$password="mypassword"; // Left empty due to privacy
$db_name="mydatabase"; // Left empty due to privacy
$tbl_name="recipe"; // Table name


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$recipe=$_POST['recipename'];
$ingredients=$_POST['ingredients'];
$instructions=$_POST['instructions'];


$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(recipename, ingredients, instructions)VALUES('$recipe', '$ingredients', '$instructions')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='recipe.php'>Back to main page</a>";
} else {
   echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Web Form

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="insert_ac.php">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><strong>Insert Data Into mySQL Database </strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="71">Recipe name</td>
            <td width="6">:</td>
            <td width="301"><input name="name" type="text" id="recipe"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ingredients</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input name="lastname" type="text" id="ingredients"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Instructions</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input name="email" type="text" id="instructions"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would love to know if anyone knows the reason the data is invisible.[image]

Image of table with no data

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Other than the obvious SQL injection vulnerability, you need to add some sort of error catching (`or die(mysql_error());`)

Comment: try adding:
to 
`$result=mysql_query($sql);`
this line
`echo mysql_error();`
it spits the error to your screen.. the data is not invisible but there has been an error.

Comment: Do you mean like the code I already have "mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");"?

Comment: Successful
Back to main page

That's what I get when submitting the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$recipe=$_POST['recipename'];
$ingredients=$_POST['ingredients'];
$instructions=$_POST['instructions'];
```

needs to be:

```
$recipe=$_POST['name'];
$ingredients=$_POST['lastname'];
$instructions=$_POST['email'];
```

You have the form field names wrong, so it is not getting a value and thus inserting empty data. If you set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` you would have gotten an error. Make sure you develop with it at that setting.

Also the `name` attribute in the form field is what the index name would be for `$_POST['INDEX_NAME']`, you are mistakingly using the `id` attribute for that.

Comment: So I should have set the input fields instead of id's I didn't realise, silly mistake. I'm still new to PHP

Comment: @LawrenceSmith silly mistakes is just a process of learning. I've had more than I can remember =o) If this solved your issue please mark it as answered, and if you have anymore questions post a comment. Have a lovely day.